# Basic Login protocol

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication

I'm wondering what the basic protocol is for storing users in a database, creating accounts, and authenticating them - with ASP.NET MVC 3 framework (using C#), and Azure SQL.

More specifically:

1.) Where in an ASP.NET C# MVC3 Visual Studio project do I write code that only runs on the back-end? Such as logging into my database as an admin, so I can write to and read from the database.

2.) Where should I make database calls from using MVC framework? Do I call a back-end function (e.g. - to create a new account in the database) from the controller?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure whether you are talking about SQL Users or Application users.

However, generally, what ASP.Net MVC applications do is:

- they use one or two defined users to connect to the database (e.g. they might define a read-write and a readonly connection for different types of queries)
- they use the ASP.Net Membership API for application-level user accounts
- they use an ORM framework like NHibernate or Entity Framework for other database access

There are lots of tutorials and articles for this sort of information out there - one place to look might be Scott Hanselman's blog - see:

- [a tutorial on using ASP.Net Membership with SQL Azure](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)
- [the Mix11 tools walkthrough - including Code First Entity Framework](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Mix11WebPlatformAndToolsKeynoteDemoScript.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1) You could use Membership (which I used to use) or simply write your own Authentication code. There are 2 drawbacks with Membership. First, there are a ton of tables and stored procedures that are installed but worse, there's no way to change a user name via the Membership API. Try telling a customer that they cannot change their username (which is usually their email address) and they'll give you weird looks.

2) Forget EF and use your own repository, which simply harnesses SPROCs. Go ahead, make a ton of changes to your EF design canvas, change the db schema, and I can guarantee you will run into issues with the "behind the scene" files at one point or another.

Comment: It's true that it is difficult to change a username in aspnet membership, but it can be done. Basically it involves recreating the user while maintaining the user identifier - and if you do the security properly the user will have to reenter the password since it is hashed, but that would fit nicely in most username change flows. Writing your own authentication logics is rarely a good idea since security should be left for the experts. (And my apologies if you _are_ a security expert :))

Comment: Well I myself am no security expert, and so would have a hard time writing my own authentication code or repository. So really I'm looking into the Best(TM) of what is available.